# How to efficiently search records and get parent records with NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: c#, queryover

I am building a platform where webshops can create their own shop.
Each shop has their own set of `Productcategory` and relations (`CategoryProductX`) to `Product` records. So `Product` records can have a relation with `ProductCategory` from different shops.
My tables look like this:

```
ProductCategory
    Id
    Name
    ShopId

CategoryProductX
    Id
    CategoryId
    ProductId

Product
    Id
    Name
```

Mapping of the relation between `ProductCategory` and `Product` looks like this:

```
private IList<CategoryProductX> products = new List<CategoryProductX>();
[Bag(0, Name = "Products", Table = "CategoryProductX", Inverse = true)]
[Key(1, Column = "CategorieId")]
[OneToMany(2, ClassType = typeof(CategoryProductX))]
public virtual IEnumerable<CategoryProductX> Products
{ 
    get { return products; } 
    protected set { products = (IList<CategoryProductX>)value; } 
}
```

I had previously implemented a search function which search products only within the `ProductCategory` the user had selected and executed the search on the client entirely. We want to change this however so that it searches through the entire catalogue of the current `Shop`.
As I don't want to always retrieve the entire catalogue from the database just to be able to execute the search on the client, we have to move this functionality on the server.

The searchresults should be a `List<ProductCategoryDTO>` containing a property `public List<ProductDTO> Products`.

I have something that works but I want to make sure this is efficient as it can be, because it will be executed each time the user enters a character in the searchbox.

```
ProductCategory categoryAlias = null;
CategoryProductX categoryProductAlias = null;
Product productAlias = null;

var query = session.QueryOver<ProductCategory>(() => categoryAlias)
    .Where(() => categoryAlias.Shop.Id == shopId)
    .JoinQueryOver(() => categoryalias.Products, () => categoryProductAlias)
    .JoinQueryOver(() => categoryProductAlias.Product, () => productAlias);

query.Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
    .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Name", searchTerm, MatchMode.Anywhere)));

ProductCategoryDTO category = null;
ProductDTO product = null;

var productResults = query.SelectList(list => list
    .Select(() => productAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => product.Id)
    .Select(() => productAlias.Name).WithAlias(() => product.Name)
    .Select(() => categoryProductAlias.CategoryId).WithAlias(() => product.CategoryId).TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ProductDTO>())
    .List<ProductDTO>();

var categories = query
    .Where(c => c.Id.IsIn(productResults.Select(p => p.CategoryId).ToArray()))
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => categoryAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => category.Id)
        .Select(() => categoryAlias.Name).WithAlias(() => category.Name)
    )
    .TransformUsing(Tranformers.AliasToBean<CategoryDTO>())
    .List<CategoryDTO>().Distinct();

if(categories.Any())
{
    foreach(var category in categories)
    {
        category.Product = productResults.Where(p => p.CategoryId == category.Id).ToList();
    }
}

Result = categories;

return Task.FromResult(0);
```

Comment: I would suggest also caching the results client side and filtering them client side as the user types so you don't have to hit the server on each keypress - eg. get say 1000 results starting with "c", and presumably show the user the top 10, then if they type "a", filter those 1000 results by "ca" etc.. and only go back to the server if you don't have enough results... or use something like elasticsearch

Comment: @MartinErnst  I have added a delay of 300ms which must pass between keystrokes before a call to the backend is executed.